# Html file using RallyLoginkey showing errors through IE

Tags: rally

I created one html file to access the rally reports using Login Key. When I open the same html file through IE I am getting below error messages like The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available and Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
No issues found when I open the same file through Google-Chrome.

Could one of you help me or suggest me with your comments in this regards?

Comment: What version of IE? Could you post the full output from the Javascript console? Your app code (minus your Login Key itself, of course) would also be quite helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am using IE8 version. Yesterday I sent you the script file. I hope you saw that. Please let me know any details required.